# Change of polynomial basis from $ P^2$ to $P^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $ P^k $ be the vector space of polynomials of degree < k, k is a natural number. Now consider the following map $F$ from $P^2$ to $P^3$

$F: P^2 \rightarrow P^3$
$f(x)  \rightarrow \int_0^x f(s) ds$

Given is the basis $1, x$ in the preimage and the basis $1, x, x^2$ in the image space. Through which Matrix A is $F$ described ?

All examples I found are change of basis in the same dimension, where the new basis is expressed in term of the old one. But here, this isn't possible because the old basis has no $x^2$.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: May I also ask (I thought about it right now) how can the integral be represented in the matrix of this linear transformation ? (I hope what I'm saying is clear)

Comment: This is not a change of basis. It's just a linear transformation. It takes a polynomial in $P_2$ and gives you a polynomial in $P_3$. As such, it is represented by a matrix with respect to the standard basis in each of the two spaces.

Comment: I'm a little bit disturbed now. Why do they give this two basis then ? Also, if they ask about the matrix of this linear transformation, I don't really know how to deal with the integral.

Comment: The only difference if the dimensions are the different is that the matrix representation of the linear transformation will be a non-square matrix (in this particular case a $3 \times 2$-matrix).

Comment: Is the matrix representing the linear transformation the following ? : (0 0, 1 0, 0 1/2) (just to be sure, comma is new line)

Comment: @Poujh If you pick the standard basis for each of the spaces, yeah, that looks like the right matrix. (Remember that you have to pick a basis before you can speak about matrix representation of vectors and linear transformations. That does not mean that _change_ of basis is always what's going on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F(1)=x$, and $F(x)=\frac12x^2$, the matrix that you are interested in is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\\0&\frac12\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Just to be sure. When we search for a matrix to represent the linear transformation, we take a basis in our preimage and look how it is affected by the linear transformation. So each column of the matrix represents one of the "old basis". Here for example, the old basis is affected by the integral in the way that 1 becomes x, and x becomes 1/2x^2. So in the first column, the 1 moves one row down to get x, and x moves one row down to get     1/2 x^2

Comment: @Poujh No. Each column of the matrix shows us how the *image* of each element of the basis of the preimage is expressed in the basis of the image space.

Comment: Yeah, so for example x become 1/2x^2 after integration. It can be described as (0 0 1/2) with respect to the new basis. ?

Comment: @Poujh Yes:$$\frac12x^2=0\times1+0\times x+\frac12\times x^2.$$